# how to get PAYLOAD value from xtify sdk in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, xtify

i'm using  new xtify sdk, in which i tried this below code,

```
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Context context, Bundle msgExtras) {
    Log.i(TAG, "-- Notification recived");
    Log.i(TAG, "Notification Title: "+ msgExtras.getString(NOTIFICATION_TITLE));
    Log.i(TAG, "Notification Content: "+msgExtras.getString(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT));
    Log.i(TAG, "Payload Data "+ msgExtras.getString("listing_id"));
    RichNotificationManger.processNotifExtras(context, msgExtras);
}
```

in msgExtra,getString("listing_id"), i 'm getting the null value.

Please tell me also that how to pass value of payload with key.

i tried in that,

```
   payload{"myKey":"myValue"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the website try to send the following json in the payload filed :

```
{"listing_id":"my_listing_id"}
```

And in the client side this is how you retrieve the data :

```
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Context context, Bundle msgExtras) {
 msgExtras.getString("listing_id")
}
```

If you're still having trouble with it, let me know.

Comment: Hi Feras, it isnt working for me ... i am sending a sample test push using the Test Implementation of Xtify, while i am receiving all the values not the payload one .. Let me know if you want any code samples from me

Answer (score 0):

With Xtify 2.0, send the following JSON:

```
{"listing_id":"my_listing_id"}
```

and on the client side use:

```
msgExtras.getString("data.listing_id");
```